# angularJS Custom directive functionality works using ng-click but not using ng-mouseOver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework, mousehover

Requirement goes like this :- I have left navigation panel which has to be in sync with the items added in the main active view by the user and has to display in tree structure. Basic idea is to provide context aware sub-view that change based on active view.

Custom directive used to display tree structure: https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/blob/master/src/abn_tree_directive.js

my HTML code: (using ng-click)

```html
<div class="add-data-request-panel" style="min-height:1071px;" 
     ng-click="expandPanel()"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="icon-drd icon-drd-diactive" ng-if="panelCollapse" ></li>
    <li class="icon-pie-chart icon-pie-active" ng-if="panelCollapse"></li>
    <li class="icon-publish-req" ng-if="panelCollapse"></li>
    <li class="icon-view-changes" ng-if="panelCollapse"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
        
<div class="data-slider-panel" style="min-height:1071px;display" ng-if="panelExpand">
   <div class="data-slider-row mtop" ng-click="collapsePanel()">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         <span class="first-char" >S</span>
         <span class="second-char">ection</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-drd icon-drd-diactive">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         Section2
         <div class="sub-slider-row-left">
            <abn-tree tree-data="mainArrayObj"></abn-tree> // passing data to tree directive
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-pie-chart icon-pie-active">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row" ng-click="collapsePanel()">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         Section3
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-publish-req">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row" ng-click="collapsePanel()">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         Section4
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-view-changes">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS implementation in my controller

```
$scope.panelExpand = false;  //setting default flag
$scope.panelCollapse = true; //setting default flag


$scope.expandPanel = function() {
 $scope.panelExpand = true;
 $scope.panelCollapse = false;
 $scope.mainArrayObj = []; // array that holds the data passed in html to custom directive
 initialJsonSeparator($scope.model.Data); // method used for iteration
};

$scope.collapsePanel = function() {
 $scope.panelExpand = false;
 $scope.panelCollapse = true;
};
```

my HTML code: (using ng-mouseover which is not working and displaying the data passed to navigation bar)

```
<div class="add-data-request-panel" style="min-height:1071px;" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" 
   ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
   <ul>
      <li class="icon-drd icon-drd-diactive"></li>
      <li class="icon-pie-chart icon-pie-active"></li>
      <li class="icon-publish-req"></li>
      <li class="icon-view-changes"></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="data-slider-panel" style="min-height:1071px;display"
   ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" ng-show="hoverEdit">
   <div class="data-slider-row mtop">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         <span class="first-char">S</span>
         <span class="second-char">ection1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-drd icon-drd-diactive">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         Section2
         <div class="sub-slider-row-left">
            <abn-tree tree-data="mainArrayObj"></abn-tree> // array that holds the data passed in html to custom directive
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-pie-chart icon-pie-active">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
          Section3
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-publish-req">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-slider-row">
      <div class="slider-row-left">
         Section4
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row-right">
         <div class="icon-view-changes">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

js Implementation for the ng-mouseOver: (while debugging all the iteration and methods executed as expected)

```
$scope.hoverIn = function() {
 this.hoverEdit = true;
 $scope.mainArrayObj = []; // array that holds the data passed in html to custom directive
 initialJsonSeparator($scope.model.Data); //method used to iterate the data
};

$scope.hoverOut = function() {
 this.hoverEdit = false;
};
```

Any solution to this issue would be of gr8 help. If there is any other better approach other than the ng-mouseOver and ng-mouseLeave to implement hover, please do let me know.

Comment: When i printed {{mainArrayObj }} in html, it was empty after using ng-mouseOver even when the data is available and methods executed as expected in my controller

Comment: What does hover edit give you as you hover and leave

Comment: hoverEdit is false when i hover and leave.. it becomes true when its hovered in the navigation div and starts executing my iteration method. But when its displayed in screen {{mainArrayObj }} is printing empty

Comment: Is hoverEdit not in $scope?  Or is it outside of your controller's closure?

Comment: hoverEdit is within my controller's closure.. after adding the data in active view...when i hover over the div class="data-slider-panel", $scope.hoverIn will get invoked and my iteration methods gets executed as expected..but when the view gets loaded {{mainArrayObj }} prints empty

Comment: As i said earlier... this implementation is working fine when i use ng-click directive in my view